# Function in VB6 (dll files) with a parameter of type variant, as in the call. net?

Tags: c#, .net, com, vb6, variant

I have a dll with a method.
This method accepts an object parameter (in .net) in vb6 it is defined as a variant, which is a vector of strings.

How can I make the call to this method on .net passing an array of strings?

Please send me an example

thanks

Comment: Is the client VB6? If so see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233284/calling-net-methods-from-vb6-via-com-visible-dll) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270613/use-net-com-in-vb6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both parties have good support for COM. I can't tell from your question whether or not the call comes from .net or VB6, but either way it will be simplest to communicate with good old fashioned COM.